# merge 3 multidimensional arrays code igniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am using codeigniter php programming and I have 3 arrays like

```
array(1) {
[1506546000]=>
object(stdClass)#34 (1) {
["purchases"]=>int(120)
}
}
array(1) {
[1506546000]=>
object(stdClass)#32 (1) {
["exchange_items"]=>int(10)
}
}
array(3) {
[1506546000]=>
object(stdClass)#40 (1) {
["production_system"]=>int(16050)
}
[1506373200]=>
object(stdClass)#33 (1) {
["production_system"]=>int(2250)
}
[1506805200]=>
object(stdClass)#39 (1) {
["production_system"]=>int(150)
}
}
```

I need to merge them in one array with the key to be like this

```
array(1) {
[1506546000]=>
["purchases"]=>int(120)
["exchange_items"]=>int(10)
["production_system"]=>int(16050)
}
array(1) {
[1506373200]=>
["purchases"]=>null
["exchange_items"]=>null
["production_system"]=>int(2250)
}
array(1) {
[1506373200]=>
["purchases"]=>null
["exchange_items"]=>null
["production_system"]=>int(150)
}
```

I used `array_merge_recursive()` but it doesn't give me exactly what I need,
So any help to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a PHP built in function that's going to do what you want to do, but I could be wrong. You could just do this:

```
<?php

$final_arr = array();

function setup()
{
    return array(
        'purchases'         => NULL,
        'exchange_items'    => NULL,
        'production_system' => NULL
    );
}

$arr1 = array(
    1506546000 => (object) array(
        'purchases' => 120
    )
);

$arr2 = array(
    1506546000 => (object) array(
        'exchange_items' => 10
    )
);

$arr3 = array(
    1506546000 => (object) array(
        'production_system' => 16050
    ),
    1506373200 => (object) array(
        'production_system' => 2250
    ),
    1506805200 => (object) array(
        'production_system' => 150
    )
);

foreach( array( $arr1, $arr2, $arr3 ) as $array )
{
    foreach( $array as $k => $v )
    {
        if( ! array_key_exists( $k, $final_arr ) )
            $final_arr[$k] = setup();

        foreach($v as $k2 => $v2)
        {
            $final_arr[$k][$k2] = $v2;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $final_arr );
echo '</pre>';
```